# Rails - Model association generates an invalid SQL query

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a rails app in which one model was built like this

```
class Forum::Thread < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :forum
  belongs_to :user
  attr_accessible :body, :title

  has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
end
```

In some point I've realized that `user` is not a good name, so I've changed it to `author`.

```
class Forum::Thread < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :forum
  belongs_to :author, class_name: 'User'
  attr_accessible :body, :title

  has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
end
```

Also, in `user` I have the following:

```
has_many :forum_threads, class_name: 'Forum::Thread', inverse_of: :author
```

But when I try to fetch the list of threads (`@user.forum_threads`, for example), it seems like rails still builds a query that refers to the old `user_id` instead for the new `author_id`.

```
 Showing /home/giladnaaman/Programming/Eclipse/Hephaestus/app/views/users/show.html.erb where line #40 raised:

SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: forum_threads.user_id: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "forum_threads"  WHERE "forum_threads"."user_id" = 1

Extracted source (around line #40):

37:                         # of Threads
38:                     </dt>
39:                     <dd>
40:                         <%= @user.forum_threads.count%> <%= link_to 'watch', '#', class: 'btn btn-mini pull-right'%>
41:                     </dd>
42:                     <br />
43:                     <dt>
```

What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you should use the foreign key and by foreign key I mean the "user_id"

Comment: But the foreign key is already 'user_id', that's the problem.

Comment: I think you are misunderstanding something. The method "belongs_to" by default looks for foreign key with the argument you specify, in your case "belongs_to :author" looks for author_id, then you specify class_name User, but not pass foreign key, which you should be user_id. I suggest reading rails guides 4.1.2.6 http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#options-for-belongs_to

Comment: So what are you suggesting? Renaming the table column back to user_id?

Comment: Have you added the author_id column to User table?

Comment: Oh, I see what you mean. You're right. `has_many :forum_threads, class_name: 'Forum::Thread', foreign_key: 'author_id'` works for me.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try setting the foreign_key? http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#options-for-belongs_to

Comment: I've tried to include `foreign_key: "author_id"` in my Thread model (and restarted `rails server`), but the error stays the same.

Comment: Did you do the same on the has_many association? http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#options-for-has_many